# Creating custom plugin for Converse.js 9.1.1

Tags: converse.js

I downloaded conversejs 9.1.1 and I am trying to learn the plugin architecture by making my own custom plugin. I looked at the http-auth plugin here to see how to add a plugin.
https://github.com/conversejs/community-plugins/tree/master/packages/http-auth

To install the plugin it directs me to the instructions here:
https://m.conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html

I understand I have to modify my webpage to whitelist the plugin, but for some reason I can't grok a few things. Here is my awesome plugin which resides in a file called Hello-World.js

```
import { converse } from "@converse/headless/core";

const plugin = {
    initialize() {
        console.error("Hello World!")
    }
}

if (typeof converse === "undefined") {
    window.addEventListener(
        'converse-loaded',
        () => converse.plugins.add("Hello-World", plugin)
    );
} else {
    converse.plugins.add("Hello-World", plugin);
}
```

1. The htpp-auth.js has no imports, but WebStorm was complaining that converse was unknown so I had to add the import. Why does the http-auth plugin not have to do that?
2. I am not sure where the plugin code is supposed to live. I added Hello-World under src/plugins/Hello-World. Is this correct?
3. Maybe related to above, but to get the plugin to actually run in addition to whitelisting it in my webpage I had to modify converse.js and add import "./plugins/Hello-World/Hello-World.js" which makes me think I am missing something obvious as I would think adding a plugin shouldn't require you to change the base code.

If it matters I am testing my plugin by running make serve in the conversejs directory and directing my web-browser (Chrome) to localhost:8000/fullscreen.html

Thanks, Wray

Answer (score 0):

> The htpp-auth.js has no imports, but WebStorm was complaining that converse was unknown so I had to add the import. Why does the http-auth plugin not have to do that?

`converse` is available as a global once `converse.js` has been loaded via the `<script>` tag.

That's why there's the `if (typeof converse === "undefined") {` check at the end of the plugin. It waits for converse.js to be loaded if `converse` isn't yet defined.

> I am not sure where the plugin code is supposed to live. I added Hello-World under src/plugins/Hello-World. Is this correct?

Most community plugins are developed in such a way that they're loaded separately via `<script>` tags. If you do it like that, it doesn't matter where they live.

> Maybe related to above, but to get the plugin to actually run in addition to whitelisting it in my webpage I had to modify converse.js and add import "./plugins/Hello-World/Hello-World.js" which makes me think I am missing something obvious as I would think adding a plugin shouldn't require you to change the base code.

You can do it like that if you want to include your plugin inside a custom build of Converse, then you can also `import` stuff from converse.

The alternative is to load your plugin separately via a `<script>` tag, but then you can't import stuff and have to use the `converse` global and the closured `_converse` object that is passed to your plugin's `initialize` function.